# any one who can help me with regex code for phone number

Tags: regex

please help me to create a regex code for these kinds of phone numbers which is followed bellow:

```
+989*********
09*********
09**-***-**-**
09** *** ** **
```

thank you

Comment: `*` means any number ?

Answer (score 1):

This matches what you want:

```
^\+989\d{9}|09\d{9}|09\d{2}[- ]\d{3}([- ]\d{2}){2}$
```

It matches `+989` and nine digits
OR it matches `09` and nine digits
OR it matches `09`, then two digits, then either a `-` or a , then two of the following: either a `-` or a  and two digits.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/qC4tX7/1

*(I assumed you wanted digits instead of asterisks)*